# Discord can't get the amount of reaction, why?

Tags: dictionary, count, discord

```
var Reactions = 0;

msg.channel.send(embed).then(sentEmbed => {
sentEmbed.react("✅");

const Posfilter = reaction => reaction.emoji.name === '✅';
sentEmbed.awaitReactions(Posfilter, { time: timeToEnd }).then(collected =>
collected.map(s => PosReactions = s.count));
```

I can't get s.count, always show 0, but

```
(collected => collected.map(s => console.log(`✅ - ${s.count}`)));
```

show the number of reactions, why and how i can fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `PosReactions` outside of `then` block?

Like this?:

```js
sentEmbed.awaitReactions(Posfilter, { time: timeToEnd }).then(collected => {
  collection.map(s => PosReactions = s.count));
});

console.log(PosReactions)
```

If so it wouldn't work since `awaitReactions` is async, so it goes on to the next code section without waiting for it.

A way to fix this is using `await` keyword, which waits for the promise to resolve or reject

```js
const collection = await sendEmbed.awaitReactions(Posfilter, { time: timeToEnd });
PosReactions = collection.map(s => PosReactions = s.count));
```

This does need to be wrapped in an async function though.

Also since you are only allowing one emoji reaction there is no point in mapping over it

```js
const collection = await sendEmbed.awaitReactions(Posfilter, { time: timeToEnd });
const reaction = collection.first();
PosReactions = reaction && reaction.count;
```

Comment: `const Posfilter = reaction => reaction.emoji.name === '✅';
const collected = sentEmbed.awaitReactions(Posfilter, { time: timeToEnd });
PosReactions = collected.map(s => PosReactions = s.count);`
TypeError: collected.map is not a function.  
  I want to get all emoji "✅" from sentEmbed Message.
I can't add "await" before sentEmbed, becouse i got error "await is only valid in async function"(everything is in async function)

Comment: and `const reaction = collection.first();`  "collection.first is not a function"

Comment: Like i said "This does need to be wrapped in an async function", because it's using `await`.

Comment: More info on async/await: https://javascript.info/async-await